Oom Killer - was it GCP ops agent memory use?
My server ran out of memory and invoked oom killer and I would very much appreciate advice as to the cause of this.
Looks normal to me except GCP ops agent memory use is around 1GB.
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686249+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.292035] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name

2024-08-31T03:32:04.686293+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.531175] [    589]     0   589   455590     5613   348160        0             0 google_cloud_op
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686294+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.541342] [    591]     0   591   310198     2641   126976        0          -999 google_guest_ag
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686294+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.551363] [    592]     0   592   311262     3032   131072        0             0 google_osconfig


I would be grateful for any advice as its not a fault I can re create.
There is 30 php-fpm processes which is how many I have set and 5 apache processes.
2024-08-31T03:32:04.179692+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.337042] php-fpm8.1 invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x140cca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE|__GFP_COMP), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
2024-08-31T03:32:04.682468+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.348768] CPU: 0 PID: 45778 Comm: php-fpm8.1 Not tainted 6.1.0-23-cloud-amd64 #1  Debian 6.1.99-1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.682636+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.358398] Hardware name: Google Google Compute Engine/Google Compute Engine, BIOS Google 06/27/2024
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683342+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.368643] Call Trace:
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683371+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.371878]  <TASK>
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683386+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.374240]  dump_stack_lvl+0x44/0x5c
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683387+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.378306]  dump_header+0x4a/0x211
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683389+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.382394]  oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683390+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.386974]  out_of_memory+0x1fd/0x4c0
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683391+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.391068]  __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.0+0xc6c/0xe30
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683391+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.521874]  ? __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.0+0xd00/0xe30
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683392+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.528034]  __alloc_pages+0x305/0x330
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683393+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.532111]  folio_alloc+0x17/0x50
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683393+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.536250]  __filemap_get_folio+0x155/0x340
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683411+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.541238]  filemap_fault+0x139/0x910
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683412+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.545569]  __do_fault+0x2e/0x80
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683413+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.549293]  do_fault+0x1b9/0x410
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683414+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.552961]  __handle_mm_fault+0x660/0xfa0
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683415+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.557640]  handle_mm_fault+0xdb/0x2d0
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683416+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.563215]  do_user_addr_fault+0x191/0x550
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683416+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.568194]  exc_page_fault+0x70/0x170
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683435+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.572418]  asm_exc_page_fault+0x22/0x30
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683436+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.576966] RIP: 0033:0x5630975fe1ad
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683437+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.580840] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at 0x5630975fe183.
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683438+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.587769] RSP: 002b:00007fff20361200 EFLAGS: 00010202
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683439+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.593503] RAX: 00007f76a0b3c420 RBX: 00007f76a1bb37c8 RCX: 0000000000000000
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683440+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.601309] RDX: 00007f76a0ad29c0 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 00007f76aa400040
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683452+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.609016] RBP: 00007f76aa414420 R08: 0000000000000042 R09: 00007f769dd3faa0
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683453+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.616657] R10: 00007f76acf41ac0 R11: 00007f76acf423c0 R12: 0000000000000000
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683454+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.624020] R13: 00007f76a0942460 R14: 00007f76aa4142f0 R15: 0000000047964ea0
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683454+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.631387]  </TASK>
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683455+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.633930] Mem-Info:
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683455+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.636732] active_anon:33000 inactive_anon:898360 isolated_anon:0
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683481+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.636732]  active_file:228 inactive_file:389 isolated_file:70
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683482+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.636732]  unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683483+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.636732]  slab_reclaimable:24356 slab_unreclaimable:9551
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683483+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.636732]  mapped:31054 shmem:32962 pagetables:4927
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683484+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.636732]  sec_pagetables:0 bounce:0
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683485+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.636732]  kernel_misc_reclaimable:0
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683485+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.636732]  free:21377 free_pcp:0 free_cma:0
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683487+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.804389] Node 0 active_anon:132000kB inactive_anon:3593440kB active_file:64kB inactive_file:1244kB unevictable:0kB isolated(
anon):0kB isolated(file):780kB mapped:123516kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB shmem:131848kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 1812480kB writeback_tmp:0kB kernel_stack:5792kB pagetables:19
708kB sec_pagetables:0kB all_unreclaimable? no
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683488+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.840108] Node 0 DMA free:14848kB boost:0kB min:256kB low:320kB high:384kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:0kB inactive_a
non:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15920kB managed:15360kB mlocked:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683489+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.872203] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2934 3886 3886 3886
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683490+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410583.877416] Node 0 DMA32 free:54592kB boost:0kB min:50824kB low:63528kB high:76232kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:64844k
B inactive_anon:2803064kB active_file:80kB inactive_file:588kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:3126072kB managed:3028156kB mlocked:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0k
B
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683491+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.032461] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 952 952 952
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683492+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.037446] Node 0 Normal free:15928kB boost:0kB min:16496kB low:20620kB high:24744kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:67156
kB inactive_anon:790416kB active_file:152kB inactive_file:1124kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:1048576kB managed:975400kB mlocked:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:428kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma
:0kB
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683493+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.068537] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683494+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.073463] Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 1*512kB (U) 0*1024kB 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 14848
kB
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683508+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.085966] Node 0 DMA32: 229*4kB (UME) 586*8kB (UME) 664*16kB (UME) 320*32kB (UME) 145*64kB (UE) 68*128kB (UME) 18*256kB (E) 9
*512kB (UE) 1*1024kB (M) 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 54692kB
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683509+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.103713] Node 0 Normal: 953*4kB (UME) 594*8kB (UME) 226*16kB (UME) 105*32kB (UME) 26*64kB (UM) 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*102
4kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 17204kB
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683510+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.118499] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683511+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.127959] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683512+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.136637] 33391 total pagecache pages
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683512+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.141065] 0 pages in swap cache
2024-08-31T03:32:04.683604+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.269572] Free swap  = 0kB
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686212+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.272792] Total swap = 0kB
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686221+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.275914] 1047642 pages RAM
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686223+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.279288] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686248+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.283449] 42913 pages reserved
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686248+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.287096] Tasks state (memory values in pages):
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686249+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.292035] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686250+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.301114] [    219]     0   219    14487      819   126976        0          -250 systemd-journal
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686250+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.310504] [    238]     0   238     5961      297    65536        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686270+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.319876] [    255]   998   255     4609      299    77824        0             0 systemd-network
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686272+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.329423] [    370]   996   370     5208      613    81920        0             0 systemd-resolve
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686273+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.338976] [    373]   997   373    22517      236    77824        0             0 systemd-timesyn
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686274+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.348872] [    375]     0   375     2065      841    49152        0             0 haveged
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686275+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.357644] [    390]   102   390     2019      169    57344        0          -900 dbus-daemon
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686276+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.367423] [    405]     0   405     7733     2559    98304        0             0 networkd-dispat
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686276+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.378046] [    407]   106   407    43612     8062   331776        0             0 redis-server
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686291+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.387516] [    412]     0   412    55444      288    77824        0             0 rsyslogd
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686292+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.522135] [    588]     0   588      723       22    45056        0             0 agetty
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686293+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.531175] [    589]     0   589   455590     5613   348160        0             0 google_cloud_op
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686294+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.541342] [    591]     0   591   310198     2641   126976        0          -999 google_guest_ag
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686294+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.551363] [    592]     0   592   311262     3032   131072        0             0 google_osconfig
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686295+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.561093] [    595]     0   595      734       22    40960        0             0 agetty
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686296+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.570595] [    597]     0   597    27028     2435   110592        0             0 unattended-upgr
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686297+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.580434] [    598]   105   598   390252    72994   815104        0             0 mariadbd
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686298+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.589957] [    617]   995   617    77074      760   106496        0             0 polkitd
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686298+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.599073] [    744]     0   744     3855      330    61440        0         -1000 sshd
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686300+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.607848] [    760]     0   760     4174      268    69632        0             0 systemd-logind
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686301+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.617485] [    782]     0   782     1005       63    49152        0             0 cron
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686301+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.626429] [   1059]   100  1059     7220     2837    98304        0             0 exim4
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686329+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.635118] [   1110]     0  1110   473703     5009   331776        0             0 google_cloud_op
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686330+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.769720] [   1152]     0  1152   495251    12263   581632        0             0 otelopscol
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686331+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.778851] [   1153]     0  1153   297611     3666   294912        0             0 fluent-bit
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686331+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.788751] [   1472]     0  1472    70962     3245   274432        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686332+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.798306] [   2104]     0  2104     3425      764    65536        0             0 apache2
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686332+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.807166] [  44643]    33 44643   305514     3063   249856        0             0 apache2
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686346+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.815855] [  44644]    33 44644   305321     3555   245760        0             0 apache2
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686347+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.825116] [  45455]    33 45455   104733    66522   778240        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686348+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.835206] [  45556]    33 45556   123425    65406   815104        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686349+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.844776] [  45705]    33 45705   103791    62700   761856        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686349+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.855704] [  45712]    33 45712    97488    33454   487424        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686350+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.865693] [  45714]    33 45714   305121     1441   245760        0             0 apache2
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686350+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.875509] [  45742]    33 45742    95952    31831   475136        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686351+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410584.885411] [  45744]    33 45744    95952    31930   475136        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686353+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.019042] [  45746]    33 45746   103124    38774   532480        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686353+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.028908] [  45748]    33 45748   100048    36057   507904        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686354+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.038459] [  45750]    33 45750   304801     1794   245760        0             0 apache2
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686355+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.047318] [  45778]    33 45778    98000    33877   491520        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686356+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.056271] [  45780]    33 45780   304641     1342   241664        0             0 apache2
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686375+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.065327] [  45808]    33 45808    94932    30659   466944        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686376+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.074356] [  45810]    33 45810    91856    27409   442368        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686377+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.083654] [  45812]    33 45812    88272    24314   413696        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686377+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.093087] [  45814]    33 45814    87764    23647   409600        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686378+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.102117] [  45816]    33 45816    87760    23696   409600        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686379+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.111071] [  45818]    33 45818    87760    23651   409600        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686392+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.120535] [  45820]    33 45820    88276    24274   413696        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686393+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.130811] [  45822]    33 45822   103536    39226   536576        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686393+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.141259] [  45824]    33 45824   102942    38595   532480        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686394+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.275568] [  45826]    33 45826   100860    36573   516096        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686396+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.285213] [  45828]    33 45828    99799    35692   507904        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686397+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.294594] [  45830]    33 45830    99799    35661   507904        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686398+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.304153] [  45832]    33 45832    98187    33788   471040        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686399+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.313612] [  45834]    33 45834    97159    32977   462848        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686399+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.322804] [  45836]    33 45836    94550    30498   442368        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686400+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.332181] [  45838]    33 45838    94554    30199   442368        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686401+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.342441] [  45840]    33 45840    93526    28949   434176        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686401+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.351636] [  45842]    33 45842    91478    26920   417792        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686420+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.361344] [  45844]    33 45844    91478    26926   417792        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686421+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.371078] [  45846]    33 45846    89363    25328   401408        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686421+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.380098] [  45848]    33 45848    87315    23204   385024        0             0 php-fpm8.1
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686422+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.389907] [  45850]   106 45850    43708     8133   319488        0             0 redis-server
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686423+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.523630] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/mar
iadb.service,task=mariadbd,pid=598,uid=105
2024-08-31T03:32:04.686423+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 kernel: [410585.541260] Out of memory: Killed process 598 (mariadbd) total-vm:1561008kB, anon-rss:291976kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UI
D:105 pgtables:796kB oom_score_adj:0
2024-08-31T03:32:05.909071+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 systemd-networkd[255]: ens4: Could not set DHCPv4 address: Connection timed out
2024-08-31T03:32:05.944539+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 google_cloud_ops_agent_diagnostics[589]: 2024/08/31 03:32:05 rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
2024-08-31T03:32:05.964966+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 systemd-networkd[255]: ens4: Failed
2024-08-31T03:32:05.966881+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
2024-08-31T03:32:06.127762+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
2024-08-31T03:32:06.142706+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
2024-08-31T03:32:06.142923+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Consumed 10min 28.708s CPU time.
2024-08-31T03:32:06.144389+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 systemd[1]: Starting gce-workload-cert-refresh.service - GCE Workload Certificate refresh...
2024-08-31T03:32:06.148026+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 systemd[1]: Starting google-oslogin-cache.service - NSS cache refresh...
2024-08-31T03:32:06.690880+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 google_oslogin_nss_cache[45854]: oslogin_cache_refresh[45854]: Refreshing passwd entry cache
2024-08-31T03:32:06.691300+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 oslogin_cache_refresh[45854]: Refreshing passwd entry cache
2024-08-31T03:32:06.734337+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 google_oslogin_nss_cache[45854]: oslogin_cache_refresh[45854]: Refreshing group entry cache
2024-08-31T03:32:06.734548+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 oslogin_cache_refresh[45854]: Refreshing group entry cache
2024-08-31T03:32:06.888927+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 systemd[1]: google-oslogin-cache.service: Deactivated successfully.
2024-08-31T03:32:06.889168+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 systemd[1]: Finished google-oslogin-cache.service - NSS cache refresh.
2024-08-31T03:32:06.925267+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: 2024-08-31T03:32:06.917Z#011error#011exporterhelper/queue_sender.go:101#011Exporting failed. Dropping data.#011{"error":
"rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = One or more TimeSeries could not be written: Points must be written in order. One or more of the points specified had an older end time than the most r
ecent point.: gce_instance{instance_id:5773321142887762676,zone:europe-west2-c} timeSeries[0-2]: agent.googleapis.com/agent/request_count{response_code:200}\nerror details: name = Unknown  desc
 = total_point_count:3  errors:{status:{code:3}  point_count:3}", "dropped_items": 3}
2024-08-31T03:32:06.927769+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper.newQueueSender.func1
2024-08-31T03:32:06.927869+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: #011/root/go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.102.0/exporterhelper/queue_sender.go:101
2024-08-31T03:32:06.927910+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/internal/queue.(*boundedMemoryQueue[...]).Consume
2024-08-31T03:32:06.927946+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: #011/root/go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.102.0/internal/queue/bounded_memory_queue.go:52
2024-08-31T03:32:06.927975+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/internal/queue.(*Consumers[...]).Start.func1
2024-08-31T03:32:06.928005+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: #011/root/go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.102.0/internal/queue/consumers.go:43
2024-08-31T03:32:06.928071+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: 2024-08-31T03:32:06.917Z#011error#011exporterhelper/queue_sender.go:101#011Exporting failed. Dropping data.#011{"error":
"rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = One or more TimeSeries could not be written: Points must be written in order. One or more of the points specified had an older end time than the most r
ecent point.: gce_instance{zone:europe-west2-c,instance_id:5773321142887762676} timeSeries[0-3]: agent.googleapis.com/agent/monitoring/point_count{status:OK}\nerror details: name = Unknown  des
c = total_point_count:4  errors:{status:{code:3}  point_count:4}", "dropped_items": 4}
2024-08-31T03:32:06.928172+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper.newQueueSender.func1
2024-08-31T03:32:06.928210+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: #011/root/go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.102.0/exporterhelper/queue_sender.go:101
2024-08-31T03:32:06.928242+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/internal/queue.(*boundedMemoryQueue[...]).Consume
2024-08-31T03:32:06.928281+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: #011/root/go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.102.0/internal/queue/bounded_memory_queue.go:52
2024-08-31T03:32:06.928318+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/internal/queue.(*Consumers[...]).Start.func1
2024-08-31T03:32:06.928369+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: #011/root/go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.102.0/internal/queue/consumers.go:43
2024-08-31T03:32:06.962333+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 gce_workload_cert_refresh[45853]: 2024/08/31 03:32:06: Done
2024-08-31T03:32:06.970206+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 systemd[1]: gce-workload-cert-refresh.service: Deactivated successfully.
2024-08-31T03:32:06.971615+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 systemd[1]: Finished gce-workload-cert-refresh.service - GCE Workload Certificate refresh.
2024-08-31T03:32:09.653676+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: 2024-08-31T03:32:09.652Z#011error#011exporterhelper/queue_sender.go:101#011Exporting failed. Dropping data.#011{"error":
"rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = One or more TimeSeries could not be written: One or more points were written more frequently than the maximum sampling period configured for the metric
.: gce_instance{instance_id:5773321142887762676,zone:europe-west2-c} timeSeries[0-199]: agent.googleapis.com/cpu/load_15m{}\nerror details: name = Unknown  desc = total_point_count:200  success
_point_count:197  errors:{status:{code:9}  point_count:3}\nrpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = One or more TimeSeries could not be written: One or more points were written more frequently
than the maximum sampling period configured for the metric.: gce_instance{instance_id:5773321142887762676,zone:europe-west2-c} timeSeries[0-199]: agent.googleapis.com/processes/disk/read_bytes_
count{owner:redis,command:redis-server,pid:45850,process:all,command_line:redis-rdb-bgsave 127.0.0.1:6379}\nerror details: name = Unknown  desc = total_point_count:200  success_point_count:123
 errors:{status:{code:9}  point_count:77}\nrpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = One or more TimeSeries could not be written: One or more points were written more frequently than the maximum
 sampling period configured for the metric.: gce_instance{zone:europe-west2-c,instance_id:5773321142887762676} timeSeries[0-27]: agent.googleapis.com/interface/errors{direction:rx,device:lo}\ne
rror details: name = Unknown  desc = total_point_count:28  errors:{status:{code:9}  point_count:28}", "dropped_items": 828}
2024-08-31T03:32:09.654223+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper.newQueueSender.func1
2024-08-31T03:32:09.654305+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: #011/root/go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.102.0/exporterhelper/queue_sender.go:101
2024-08-31T03:32:09.654359+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/internal/queue.(*boundedMemoryQueue[...]).Consume
2024-08-31T03:32:09.654414+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: #011/root/go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.102.0/internal/queue/bounded_memory_queue.go:52
2024-08-31T03:32:09.654465+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/internal/queue.(*Consumers[...]).Start.func1
2024-08-31T03:32:09.654542+00:00 ssd-lamp-2x-wp-aug24 otelopscol[1152]: #011/root/go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.102.0/internal/queue/consumers.go:43


looks like I was making an error.  Actual memory use per process is RSS column x 4kb.
So my memory use is:
not php-fpm - 600mb
php-fpm - 4GB
php-fpm per process - 4000/30 = 136mb
calculate pm.max_children (tot ram - 1gb / process size)
3000/136 = 22
edit php-fpm
sudo nano /etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 22
pm.max_requests = 1000
Hopefully wont crash again !

and of course: sudo service php8.1-fpm restart

If only memory calculations were that simple - then we wouldn't need OOM Killer.
